# How do "per-cpu" variables work?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

With the per-cpu variables in the Linux kernel, each processor on the system gets its own copy of that variable. In general, the memory can be accessed by any processor. How is this assured that each processor is getting an exclusive copy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978959/how-is-percpu-pointer-implemented-in-kernel